# Message Required String parameter 'searchBook' is not present

Tags: spring, search, crud

I'm trying to make CRUD+spring app which create/remove/update books. And everything work fine, but searching a book from the DB. Help me please. What's wrong with my method "searchBook"?

```
    @Controller
public class BookController {

    private BookService bookService;
    private final int pageSize = 10;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "bookService")
    public void setBookService(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/getAllBooks"})
    public ModelAndView getAllBooks() {
        List<Book> bookList = bookService.getAllBooks();
        return new ModelAndView("books", "books", bookList);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book) {
        if (book.getId() == 0) {
            this.bookService.addBook(book);
        } else {
            this.bookService.updateBook(book);
        }

        return "redirect:/books";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}")
    public String removeBook(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        this.bookService.removeBook(id);

        return "redirect:/books";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}")
    public String editBook(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("book", this.bookService.getBookById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listBooks", this.bookService.getAllBooks());

        return "books";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "bookdata/{id}")
    public String bookData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("book", this.bookService.getBookById(id));

        return "bookdata";
    }

    @RequestMapping("searchBook")
    public ModelAndView searchBook(@RequestParam("searchBook") String title){
        List<Book> booksList = bookService.getAllBooks(title);
        return new ModelAndView("booksearch", "booksList", booksList);
    }
}
```

There's a books.jsp:

```
    </head>
<br/>
<h4><a href="../../index.jsp">Back to main menu</a></h4>
<br/>
<div>
    <form action="searchBook">
        <div class="row">
            <div><h2>Search books by title:</h2></div>
            <div><input type="text" title="searchBook" id="searchBook"
                        placeholder="type title here.."></div>
            <br/>
            <div><input type='submit' value='Search'/></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead style="background-color: #b39b89;">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">ID</th>
            <th width="120">Title</th>
            <th width="120">Author</th>
            <th width="120">Description</th>
            <th width="60">ISBN</th>
            <th width="10">Print Year</th>
            <th width="120">Read Already</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${bookList}" var="book">
            <tr>
                <td>${book.id}</td>
                <td>${book.bookTitle}</td>
                <td>${book.bookAuthor}</td>
                <td>${book.description}</td>
                <td>${book.isbn}</td>
                <td>${book.printYear}</td>
                <td>${book.readAlready}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${book.id}'/>">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${book.id}'/>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

There's a structure of my project: http://clip2net.com/s/3ON3F6n

There's a getAllBooks() method from BookDaoimpl:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks(String bookName) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE BOOK_TITLE like '%" + 
bookName + "%'";
        List<Object[]> bookObjects = session.createQuery(query).list();
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for (Object[] bookObject : bookObjects) {
            Book book = new Book();
            int id = (int) bookObject[0];
            String title = (String) bookObject[1];
            String description = (String) bookObject[2];
            String author = (String) bookObject[3];
            int isbn = (int) bookObject[4];
            int printYear = (int) bookObject[5];
            int readAlready = (int) bookObject[6];
            book.setId(id);
            book.setBookTitle(title);
            book.setDescription(description);
            book.setBookAuthor(author);
            book.setIsbn(isbn);
            book.setPrintYear(printYear);
            book.setReadAlready(readAlready);
            books.add(book);
        }
        System.out.println(books);

        return books;
    }
```

There's a MySQL DB:http://clip2net.com/s/3ON4e7o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to add the **name** attribute inside your  tag. Add name="searchBook" inside

```
<form action="searchBook">
    <div class="row">
        <div><h2>Search books by title:</h2></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="searchBook" id="searchBook"
                    placeholder="type title here.."></div>
        <br/>
        <div><input type='submit' value='Search'/></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. But now I receive a new exception: Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: books is not mapped [FROM books...

How can I map it? After a job my brain doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

When I use `form` and `c:forEach` as nested, I got that exception and I removed the form tag.

It was like this:

```
<frm:form modelAttribute="" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Kitap ID</td>
                <td>Kitabın Adı</td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${kitaplar}" var="kitap">
                <c:url var="updateLink" value="kitap-ver">
                    <c:param name="kitap.ad" value="${kitap.id}" />
                </c:url>
                <tr>
                    <td>${kitap.id}</td>
                    <td>${kitap.ad}</td>
                    <td><button onclick="window.location.href='${updateLink}'"
                            class="update-button">Kitabı Ver</button></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        </frm:form>
```

Solution is:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Kitap ID</td>
                <td>Kitabın Adı</td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${kitaplar}" var="kitap">
                <c:url var="updateLink" value="kitap-ver">
                    <c:param name="kitap.ad" value="${kitap.id}" />
                </c:url>
                <tr>
                    <td>${kitap.id}</td>
                    <td>${kitap.ad}</td>
                    <td><button onclick="window.location.href='${updateLink}'"
                            class="update-button">Kitabı Ver</button></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
```